# The IControllerFactory 'Munq.MVC.MunqControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'

Tags: iis, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-2

My client has legacy application based on ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework which runs well on WinSrv 2008 R2 VM. I've cloned this machine, changed IP, hostname etc. and this cloned machine was upgraded to newest WinSrv 2019 (first 2012, then 2016 etc.). The goal was migrate this app on new server for security reason.
After migration I have noticed error which cause showing this information in browser:
[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUoa4.png)
There is an entry in Event Viewer

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2020-05-07 07:53:21 
Event time (UTC): 2020-05-07 05:53:21 
Event ID: 985ed8fb4df44033957afac395d798ea 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT-1-132333044000403533 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\websites\MY_WEBSITE.COM\www\ 
    Machine name: WINSRV2019 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 15700 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\MY_WEBSITE.COM 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Munq.MVC.MunqControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: https://MY_WEBSITE.COM:443/ 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: MY.IP.ADDRESS 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\MY_WEBSITE.COM 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 8 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\MY_WEBSITE.COM 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details:
```

This happens regularly until I refresh browser and then application works fine. I don't have access to documentation.

Comment: The exception occur when you deploy the application or every time you restart IIIS application?

Comment: Everyday when I try open the site. Then I refresh them and the exception won't occur.